# Linux embedded: change time zone

Tags: embedded, timezone

I'm working on an embedded system with linux. I'm trying to change the timezone used by the operating system and I'm doing this by copying the timezone file from /usr/share/zoneinfo to /etc/localtime (ie.: #cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Rome /etc/localtime).

So far so good: the time change accordingly. Anyway there are two weird things:

1. if I print the file /etc/timezone I found "Universal" and not /Europe/Rome as I would expect
2. I tried to simulate the automatic time change when the daylight saving time occurs but it seems that the time still remain at the old value.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A copy of the zoneinfo file does not change the /etc/timezone file.

Comment: Thanks ott, but what I can do more? Could be this the cause of the other problem (the missing automatic datetime update on daylight saving time)?

Comment: What libc is the embedded system running? (e.g. Glibc, ucLibc, dietlibc, …) What userland utilities?

Comment: I'm not sure of what kind of libc are installed but I assume glibc. How can I check this? Moreover at what kind of utilities are you referring?

Comment: Might be a stupid question but does the system have `tzselect` on it? I don't think using `ln` to the zoneinfo files is the appropriate way to do this.

Comment: I think it's safer to copy the file from zoneinfo to /etc/localtime.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing, but the time doesn't automatically change on DST.